# how many values to a single ID

Tags: excel, count, excel-formula

I can't find how to solve one question. I have list of ClientID, also i have a list of agreement dates.

```
CLIENT_ID   AGREEMENT_DATE
1            01/03/2012
2            01/05/2013
5            11/10/2013
3            01/06/2014
5            06/08/2015
```

i need to find out how many agreements had a single Client? and if there are several agreements i need to show which was first, second and so on.

As a result i would have:

```
ClientID  CountOfAgreements  
5                2
1                1
2                1
3                1
```

than:

```
ClientID  AgreementOrder
5         11/10/2013
5         06/08/2015
```

Comment: Try a [COUNTIF function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34) than*[sic]* something akin to [Multiple Ranked Returns from INDEX(…) with Duplicate Values](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/wiki/office_2010-excel/multiple-ranked-returns-from-index-with-duplicate/0f258553-fd5f-47bb-99f1-ec72dc4e6135).

Comment: Please do not deface your questions once they have received an answer.

Answer (score 1):

First make a pivot table.
select all of the data of your table and choose the insert-> pivot table.
make the pivot on anew sheet or at the same sheets.. Whatever you like.
For the rows grab the ClientId and for the values grab the agreement_date
this will result your first question.
For the 2nd question, you can make a manipulation of your raw data sheet.
Just make a copy of it to anew sheet.
and on open a third column that uses the function countif
the first argument will be the current clientID (if the first raw is the header than it will be the cell a2,and the 2nd argument will be a:a meaning you want to count the times that each Cid is found in your list
to simplify, if your 1st data row  2 paste for c2 cell =COUNTIF(a:a,A2)
grab the cell to the end of your data.
now each raw will show you how many times it appears in the list.
use the filter (data-filter) to filter the values below 2 and there is your 2nd answer.

Comment: Ido, thank you for your answer. I've done pivot table and have the sum of agreements for each client, but , sorry, i do not understand how can i order the agreements? besides ordering i want to know how many days is difference between these agreements - f.e. ClientID = 5, first agreement is on 01/03/2012, the second agreement is on 02/03/2012. i need to order these agreements by date and then count how many days is difference between these agreements.

Comment: To order the agreements after you filter the clients with only one row, just press then arrow on the count column and choose sort largest to smallest or whatever other sort you like

Comment: For you additional question sort the client ID and add an additional column d and add the function =IF(A2=A3,B2-B3,""), that means if it the same client than show the number of days, else show nothing. i

Comment: I am very sorry, i can not understand: in my worksheet (not pivot table) i have to write formula =COUNTIF(A2,A:A)  , where A2 is CLIENTID. when i grab it to the end , i have only "1" value. but i want to display agreement sequence number...

Comment: Forgive me she knows, the correct is  =COUNTIF(a:a,A2). It wont show the serial number but If I understand you correctly you wont need it... just filter all the values of column c with values less than 1 and then sort the rest of them by clinetid and then by date.

Comment: i just need If customer has multiple aggrements, to show which aggrement is first, which second, third etc